# insering the hashed password into sqlite3 table

Tags: python, sqlite, werkzeug

[[image: error message on terminaldb_table]

Hi I'm trying to insert a hashed password using;

*werkzeug.security.generate_password_hash(password, method='pbkdf2:sha256', salt_length=8)*

but I'm getting internal server errors because of the line I've highlighted on the first image of the error screenshot.

I'm using CS50 IDE, python, sqlite3, werkerzeug security library

TIA

Here my code for the route:

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user"""

    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return apology("must provide username", 403)

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("must provide password", 403)

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password2"):
            return apology("must re-type password", 403)

        # Check the password match
        if request.form.get("password") != request.form.get("password2"):
            return apology("your password didn't match")

        # Query database for existing usernames
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username", username=request.form.get("username"))

        # Ensure username not exists
        if len(rows) == 1:
            return apology("username exists, please select another")

        # Otherwise insert the user to the users TABLE
        else:
            hashed_pass = generate_password_hash((request.form.get("password")), method='pbkdf2:sha256', salt_length=len(request.form.get("password")))
            db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES (:username, ?)",
                        username=request.form.get("username"), hash=hashed_pass)

        # Return apology if cannot register
        # Query database for username to check
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username", username=request.form.get("username"))

        if len(rows) != 1:
            return apology("Sorry something went wrong, please try again")

        # If register succesful
        else:
            return redirect("/login")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("register.html")
```

Comment: **Inconsistent paramstyle**. Shouldn't it look like this: `INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES (:username, :hash)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your insert into users should look like

```
sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES (?, ?)"
values = (request.form.get("username"), hashed_pass)
db.execute.execute(sql, values)
```

OR

```
db.execute.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES (?, ?)", (request.form.get("username"), hashed_pass))
```

Comment: I've tried both and also tried changing % to ? as value placeholders, unfortunately still getting internal errors for that lines

Comment: @cetins I believe the errors are not the same this time - isnt it?

Comment: i didn't aware that sorry, only read that "error - line 156 in register". But I've changed the line as in the comments `INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES (:username, :hash)` , now it works